# How to deal with sub-directories in setup.py while using python setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

#### In my package, there exits a static directory with a few sub-directories in it.

#### Before finding a solution, I have to list all the sub-directories just like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='my-package',
    ......
    packages=find_packages(),
    test_suite='nose.collector',
    package_data={'my-app': ['VERSION', 'static/css/*.css', 'static/js/*.js', 'static/images/*.jpg', 'static/images/*.png', 'static/*.png', 'static/*.js', 'templates/*', 'etc/*']},
    include_package_data=True,
```

)

I have ever tried just a single `static/*`, but it failed to work.
Then I tried to list all the sub-directories and all file types, and it works well.
However, what can I do if there are thousands of sub-directories in `static`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate os.walk?

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply remove **include_package_data=True** or edit the **MANIFEST.in**

> **include_package_data**
>       If set to `True`, this tells `setuptools` to automatically include any
>       data files it finds inside your package directories, **that are either under
>       CVS or Subversion control, or which are specified by your `MANIFEST.in`**
>       file.

[check this example](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/blob/master/MANIFEST.in)

[check here](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/setuptools.txt) for more info